# malloc in pointer received as argument

Tags: c, malloc, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing an binary search tree but for some reasons I 'm not able to add a node

my: input was :

```
a.value = 5;
add_bst_node(&t,a);
```

mystructures:

```
typedef struct BST_node{
 entity value;
 struct BST_node* left;
 struct BST_node* right;
}BST_node;

typedef struct BST_tree{
 BST_node* root;
}BST_tree;
```

my code for add a node:

```
void add_bst_node2(BST_node* root,entity* e){
 if(!root){
  root = (BST_node*)malloc(sizeof(BST_node));
  root->value = *e;
  root->left = NULL;
  root->right = NULL;
  return;
 }
 else if(great_than(&root->value,e))
  add_bst_node2(root->left,e);
 else
  add_bst_node2(root->right,e);
 }

 void add_bst_node(BST_tree* t,entity e){
  add_bst_node2(t->root,&e);
  printf("%d\n",t->root==NULL);
 }
```

Someone can explayn why I'can't add a node?

Comment: `root` is a local variable in function `add_bst_node2`. Setting it to a value is effective only within the scope of the function (during runtime). You should call `add_bst_node2(&t->root...)`, change the function prototype to take `BST_node** root`, and set `*root = ...`.

Comment: Try changing `void add_bst_node2(BST_node* root,entity* e)` to `void add_bst_node2(BST_node* &root,entity* e)`

Comment: @LPs: So what's the point in passing `root` as input argument?

Comment: @GauravSehgal: The question is tagged *C*, not *C++*.

Comment: @barakmanos. Sorry My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from not passing double pointer to `BST_node` (i.e. `BST_node**`) in `add_bst_node2()` as noted in the comments, you also didn't implement the function properly.

Your implementation never really adds a node, but instead in enters into infinite recursion.

Here you can find some clean theory about BST - http://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-binary-search-tree/

Here is an untested correction of your code. *Note that here we pass pointer to `BST_tree` instead of `BST_node`*

```
void add_bst_node2(BST_tree* tree,entity* e){
    if(!tree->root){
        /* If the binary search tree is empty, we just create a root node */
        tree->root = bst_create_node(e);
        return;
    }

    int is_left  = 0;
    BST_node* current_node = tree->root;
    BST_node* prev   = NULL;

    /* Traverse the tree until we find the proper position for the new node.
     * The position is denoted by 'current_node'
     */
    while(current_node != NULL) {
        prev = current_node;

        if(greater_than(&current_node->value, e)) {
            is_left = 1;
            current_node = current_node->left;
        } else {
            is_left = 0;
            current_node = current_node->right;
        }
    }

    /* We finally know the position where we should add the new node */
    if(is_left)
        prev->left = bst_create_node(e);
    else
        prev->right = bst_create_node(e);
}
```

We introduce another function for creating and initializing a node...

```
BST_node *bst_create_node(entity *e)
{
    BST_node *n = malloc(sizeof(BST_node));

    n->value = *e;
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;

    return n;
}
```

And finally we change `add_bst_node()`

```
void add_bst_node(BST_tree* t,entity e){
    add_bst_node2(t, &e);
    printf("%d\n", t->root==NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it seems, a is a struct BST_node and value is a variable in it. You have to either pass the value to the function and handle the node creation there, or pass the whole constructed node and just point to it from the existing tree.

Answer (score 0):

first thing is that you put an unnecessary structure BST_tree.You do it in simple way  like

```
                 struct node
                {
                    int value;
                    node* left;
                    node* right;
                };
                struct node* root;
```

I suggest you try with this code

```
        struct node* insert(struct node* r, int data)
        {
          if(r==NULL) // BST is not created created
          {
               r = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // create a new node
               r->value = data;  // insert data to new node
              // make left and right childs empty
               r->left = NULL;   
               r->right = NULL;
          }
         // if the data is less than node value then we must put this in left sub-tree
          else if(data < r->value){ 
               r->left = insert(r->left, data);
          }
         // else this will be in the right subtree
         else {
               r->right = insert(r->right, data);
          }
         return r;
   }`
```

`

Comment: Note: When one looks at `r = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));`, there is a question, was the correct type used?  If instead code was `r = malloc(sizeof *r);`, there would be no question of correctness.  The 2nd is certainly easier to code, maintain and review.